# How can a CALayer delegate trigger display updates (during animations) for a custom property?

Tags: ios, macos, core-animation

`CALayer` seems to have *almost* everything required to add properties to a layer at runtime, without subclassing, using a delegate and/or the layer's `actions` property. However, one thing I have not figured out is how to trigger display updates when one of these dynamic properties changes in an animation.

I know how do this in a custom subclass of `CALayer`: simply define the properties in the subclass, mark them `@dynamic`, and override `needsDisplayForKey:` and return `YES` for the custom properties. Then `display` will be invoked during animations, which, by default, will even trigger a call to the layer delegate's `drawLayer:inContent:` method, if present (though it's of questionable usefulness, given that you've already got this subclass where you can implement `drawInContext:`). However, I am trying to see if this is possible without subclassing CALayer.

I can get as far as supporting updates outside of animations using only a layer delegate, by installing a `CAAction` in the layer's `actions` property, or implementing `actionForLayer:forKey:` in the layer delegate, and having that action send a `setNeedsDisplay` message to the layer. However, `actionForKey:` is apparently not called during an animation (makes sense, since it is used to trigger implicit animations), and there is no equivalent to `needsDisplayForKey:` in the layer delegate protocol, that I can see.

So, is there any way to tell `CALayer` to call `display` for custom properties besides the above? Or is it not possible to implement animatable custom layer properties in a layer delegate alone? It seems like Apple would prefer one to use delegation when possible, but without a way to refresh the layer contents during an animation, the delegate interface is incomplete. Any suggestions?

Comment: Let me ask you this: how would you mark this property as `@dynamic`, which you know you need to do?

Comment: @matt: If you're not subclassing, you can't, of course. But it doesn't seem to matter for anything else; all `@dynamic` does is tell the compiler that some accessor methods will be generated at runtime. But even without accessors, CALayer lets you add virtual properties using `valueForKey:` and `setValue:forKey:`. Like I said, it all works except for triggering `display` updates during animations. Maybe it's not supposed to work, but, man, they came so close!

Comment: Well, you don't actually need `@dynamic` as long as you don't try to call this thing via implicit property animation - if you are going to make a CABasicAnimation with a key path, then `needsDisplayForKey` (and a drawing implementation) is _all_ you need. So surely you can do it that way?

Comment: @matt, yes, I can implement `needsDisplayForKey:` _in a CALayer subclass_, but I don't see how to provide the equivalent using only a layer delegate. That's what I'm trying to figure out (if it's possible).

Comment: Aha. No, I don't see how to do that either. Fascinating idea, but clearly they didn't build that into the delegate model. You could file a feature request, but don't hold your breath: I doubt they want to mess with this, since the entire house of cards depends on it.

Comment: No, and any future addition would not be backward compatible, so it's not much help. I may make a little CALayer subclass (or monkey-patch `needsDisplayForKey:`) to add a new delegate method for my own use, but for the time being, the subclass implementation will do. Thanks for your input, @matt!

Comment: Damn! Why didn't I find your question earlier. I tried the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62421716/ and spent significant time with it.