# Why can't I animate a custom property on the UIView default backgorund layer?

Tags: ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I want to animate the UIView default background layer. In `viewDidLoad` I'm adding my custom property to animate to the view with:

```
self.layer.delegate = self;
[self.layer setValue:0 forKey:@"value"];
```

as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Key-ValueCodingExtensions/Key-ValueCodingExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH12-SW3).

The setter method of the value to change looks like this and updates the added custom property on the background layer:

```
- (void)setValue:(NSInteger)value
{
  _value = value;
  [self.layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:value] forKey:@"value"];
  [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

And in `actionForLayer:forKey:` overwritten in my view I'm returning an animation, as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/ReactingtoLayerChanges/ReactingtoLayerChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH7-SW1), which should animate from the current value to the new set value like this:

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForLayer:(CALayer*)layer forKey:(NSString*)key
{
  if([key isEqualToString:@"value"])
  {
    CAAnimation* action = (CAAnimation*)[self actionForLayer:layer forKey:@"backgroundColor"];

    if(action != (CAAnimation*)[NSNull null])
    {

      CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
      animation.keyPath           = @"value";
      animation.fromValue         = [self.layer valueForKey:@"value"];
      animation.toValue           = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:_value];
      animation.beginTime         = action.beginTime;
      animation.duration          = action.duration;
      animation.speed             = action.speed;
      animation.timeOffset        = action.timeOffset;
      animation.repeatCount       = action.repeatCount;
      animation.repeatDuration    = action.repeatDuration;
      animation.autoreverses      = action.autoreverses;
      animation.fillMode          = action.fillMode;
      animation.timingFunction    = action.timingFunction;
      animation.delegate          = action.delegate;

      [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"value"];
    }
  }

  return [super actionForLayer:layer forKey:key];
}
```

And I draw my view content like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextClearRect(context, rect);
  [self drawARainbowUnicorn:context];;
}
```

From my view controller I do an block animation like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0 animations:
^{
  self->_myView.value = self->_myView.maximumValue;
}];
```

What I see is that the value always appears as animated on the final position. What I would expect is that the value would animate to that position in the given time.

All the examples I found add a separate layer to animate like [this](https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS/blob/master/DRCircularProgress/DRCircularProgressView.m)
or [this](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/07/custom-property-uiview-block-animation/) 
or [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/make-apis-like-apple-animatable-view-properties-in-swift-4349b2244cea) and I'm aware of this StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14192816/create-a-custom-animatable-property) and some others I found.

I also had a look at this older [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/sc2284/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014302-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from Apple. They also create a CALayer subclass. But why is that needed?

I don't understand why the default background layer shouldn't do it as well. What do I miss here?